# skip first two elements in an enumeration -- python

Tags: python, enumerate

This is not what I want from enumerate:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter']

>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start =2))

[(2, 'Spring'), (3, 'summer'), (4, 'fall'), (5, 'winter')]
```

This IS the functionality I want from enumerate:

```
 >>> list(enumerate(seasons, start =2))
[(2, 'fall'), (3, 'winter')]
```

**See the difference?**
The first one just says, "fine I'll call your 0th element 2 if you really want me to"

The second one says, "I understand that you just want to begin the loop at the second index, much like range(2, len(seasons)) would do"

**Is there no way to do this simply with enumerate?**

Comment: No, not with enumerate, enumerate always yields something for each item in the iterable you give it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just slice the first two elements?

```
print(list(enumerate(seasons[2:], start=2)))
```

Output:

```
[(2, 'fall'), (3, 'winter')]
```

To understand what is going on with enumerate and the start. Try iterating over it to see what it outputs:

```
for i, v in enumerate(seasons, start=2):
    print(i, v)
```

As you can see your `i`, which simply increments along iterating through your `seasons` list is what starts at 2. But each value in the list is actually from the start of your list. This just further proves that `start` does not have anything to do with the actual starting point of your list iteration.

Comment: While this was my first attempt as well and works for lists, it won't work for any `iterable`, i.e. it won't work on the ones that are not `subscriptable`. On the other hand, the answer by @awesoon actually works for any `iterable`.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in order to take a slice of an iterable:

```
In [9]: from itertools import islice

In [10]: list(islice(enumerate(seasons), 2, None))
Out[10]: [(2, 'fall'), (3, 'winter')]
```

Comment: This, thank you. Your solution works for any `iterable` - and I'm honestly surprised this question/answer isn't getting more attention.